# Python histogram with points and error bars

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram, point

I want to plot a histogram with points and error bars. I do not want bar or step histograms. Is this possible? Google has not helped me, I hope you can. Also it should not be normalized. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using numpy and matplotlib, you can get the bin edges and counts using `np.histogram()`, then use `pp.errorbar()` to plot them:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as pp

x = np.random.randn(10000)
counts,bin_edges = np.histogram(x,20)
bin_centres = (bin_edges[:-1] + bin_edges[1:])/2.
err = np.random.rand(bin_centres.size)*100
pp.errorbar(bin_centres, counts, yerr=err, fmt='o')

pp.show()
```

[image]

I'm not sure what you mean by 'normalized', but it would be easy to, for example, divide the counts by the total number of values so that the histogram sums to 1.

The bigger question for me is what the errorbars would actually *mean* in the context of a histogram, where you're dealing with absolute counts for each bin.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this in pure Matplotlib, using `matplotlib.pyplot.hist` to draw the histogram.

```py
import numpy as np               # Only used to generate the data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randn(1000)

plt.figure()

# Matplotlib's pyplot.hist returns the bin counts, bin edges,
# and the actual rendered blocks of the histogram (which we don't need)
bin_counts, bin_edges, patches = plt.hist(x, bins=30)
bin_centres = (bin_edges[:-1] + bin_edges[1:]) / 2

# Generate some dummy error values, of the same dimensions as the bin counts
y_error = np.random.rand(bin_counts.size)*10

# Plot the error bars, centred on (bin_centre, bin_count), with length y_error
plt.errorbar(x=bin_centres, y=bin_counts,
             yerr=y_error, fmt='o', capsize=2)

plt.show()
```

[image: Histogram figure with error bars]